# Ruby produces correct path, but browser says "something wrong". Manual "Enter" works on the same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This problem looks funny, but I do not get it.
as part of the :update method the program goes to the path in the browser ../1/edit. Looks absolutely correct, but the browser gives me an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong."
If I press **Enter in the same generated path** (after it was created by the program), it works. Beats me

The path generated by the program is:
https://art-classes-maxviskov.c9users.io/artclasses/1/edit. Like I said, when called from the program, I have an error. After just pressing "Enter", it goes to the correct form.

This is the result from the program

This is the result after pressing enter at the same path

[image]

This is the code in _artclass.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Update", edit_artclass_path(artclass), method: :update %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Silly question. Why do you have method: :update in your link_to? You are doing a get to the edit route, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove `method: :update` in your `link_to` as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Update", edit_artclass_path(artclass) %>
```

Comment: WORKS! Thank you! So what I did was a duplication? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Not a duplication, though. You access the edit form via get. The update happens when you submit the form. Please accept the answer if it was satisfactory to you.